# RaspberryPi webiopi script error doesn't work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, whitespace, indentation, webiopi

I want to experiment with the RaspberryPi, but the .py code doesn't work. It gives me a lot of errors.

- a space error
- indentation error: `expected an indented block " global VELUX_STATE, AUTO_mode "`

I only copied the code from the official forum, that works for other people.

Link:
http://egrasland.blogspot.fr/2014/01/control-your-velux-roller-shutter-with.html

I copy the code and paste in "sudo nano script.py"

What do I do wrong ?

Furthermore, the code from the official webiopi from RaspberryPi doesn't work either for me. Debug gives error, and the program doesn't start.

Link: https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/Tutorial_Basis

Comment: Whitespace matters in Python, make sure you copy all indentations, or fix it if it's broken in a downloaded / checked out file.

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you're running and it throws an error?

Comment: you have installed webiopi?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

The code I used is:

Python server script :

```
import webiopi import datetime

GPIO = webiopi.GPIO     
VELUX_UP = 17 # GPIO pin using BCM numbering VELUX_DOWN = 18 # GPIO pin using BCM numbering VELUX_STOP = 27 # GPIO pin using BCM numbering     
VELUX_STATE = 0 # DOWN AUTO_MODE = 1     
HOUR_UP  = 9   # Turn Velux UP at HOUR_DOWN = 19 # Turn Velux Down at     
# setup function is automatically called at WebIOPi startup 
def setup():   global VELUX_STATE, AUTO_MODE     
    # set the GPIO used for VELUX command to output  
    GPIO.setFunction(VELUX_UP, GPIO.OUT)   
    GPIO.setFunction(VELUX_DOWN,GPIO.OUT)

    # STOP function not used at this time   
    GPIO.setFunction(VELUX_STOP,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_STOP, GPIO.LOW)

    # retrieve current datetime   now = datetime.datetime.now()     
    if (AUTO_MODE==1):
        # test time
        if ((now.hour >= HOUR_UP) and (now.hour < HOUR_DOWN)):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_UP, GPIO.HIGH)
            webiopi.sleep(0.2)
            GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_UP, GPIO.LOW)
            VELUX_STATE = 1
        else: 
            GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_DOWN, GPIO.HIGH)
            webiopi.sleep(0.2)
            GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_DOWN, GPIO.LOW)
            VELUX_STATE = 0

# loop function is repeatedly called by WebIOPi  
def loop():   global VELUX_STATE, AUTO_MODE     
    # retrieve current datetime   now = datetime.datetime.now()     
    if (AUTO_MODE==1):
        # toggle VELUX UP all days at the correct time
        if ((now.hour == HOUR_UP) and (now.minute == 0) and (VELUX_STATE == 0)):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_UP, GPIO.HIGH)
            webiopi.sleep(0.2)
            GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_UP, GPIO.LOW)
            VELUX_STATE = 1 #UP

        # toggle VELUX DOWN all days at the correct time
        if ((now.hour == HOUR_DOWN) and (now.minute == 0) and (VELUX_STATE == 1)):
            GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_DOWN, GPIO.HIGH)
            webiopi.sleep(0.2)
            GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_DOWN, GPIO.LOW)
            VELUX_STATE = 0 #DOWN
            # gives CPU some time before looping again   webiopi.sleep(1)

# destroy function is called at WebIOPi shutdown 
def destroy():   
    GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_UP, GPIO.LOW)   
    GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_DOWN, GPIO.LOW)   
    GPIO.digitalWrite(VELUX_STOP, GPIO.LOW)


@webiopi.macro def getHours():
    return "%d;%d" % (HOUR_UP, HOUR_DOWN)

@webiopi.macro def setHours(on, off):
    global HOUR_UP, HOUR_DOWN
    HOUR_UP = int(on)
    HOUR_DOWN = int(off)
    return getHours()

@webiopi.macro def getAutoMode():
    return "%d" % (AUTO_MODE)

@webiopi.macro def setAutoMode():
    global AUTO_MODE

    if AUTO_MODE:
        AUTO_MODE=0
    else:
        AUTO_MODE=1
    return getAutoMode()
```

The debug can't I post here because its on my RaspberryPi and the browser is to slow :)
But the first error he give is the dubble spaces by the comment VELUX UP
"HOUR_UP  = 9   # Turn Velux UP at"
I solved this but then is it the error 
"def setup():
  global VELUX_STATE, AUTO_MODE"

Why?

Thanks!